# How to create a simple head/center/foot layout?

Tags: html, css

What I want to do sounds so extremly easy but I can't get it working for some reason... I want a block element with a specific size which has three child block elements: A header, a center area and a footer. It must have the following characteristics:

- The header and footer only takes as much height as needed by the content. This content is dynamic so I can't use fixed sizes here. So let's say the text in the header is localized. It can be a short english text (one line) or a long french text (which wraps into two lines).
- The center area takes all the other space. And with this I mean it REALLY takes all the space and it is not just positioned at the top of the center. So if the center element has a background color, then this color must be visible for the whole space between header and footer. Or if the center element is an image then it must be stretched into the area between header and footer.
- All sizes are unknown at creation time, so using absolute positioning doesn't work. Also using the usual margin trick on the center element doesn't work because the height of the header/footer is unknown because it is dynamic.
- No JavaScript hacks.
- Must work in IE7+, FF3+, Chrome and Safari.

So let's take this example code:

```
<div style="width: 512px; height: 512px">
  <div class="head">This is the header</div>
  <div class="center">This is the center area</div>
  <div class="foot">This is the footer</div>
</div>
```

In the end it should look like this:

```
+--------------------------+
| This is the header       |
+--------------------------+
| This is the center area  |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
| This is the footer       |
+--------------------------+
```

How can I do this? Even with an old-school table and using height="100%" for the center cell I can't get it working because the table is too large then in IE7 (Center area is 512px, so table itself is 512px plus the height of the header and footer cell).

What I'm searching for is some CSS code to make the above HTML code (Or any alternative HTML code, even a real HTML table is allowed) appear as described above and matching all criterias as listed above.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

Here's another fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/zDfHs/

The content won't have height 100% but you can change that with JavaScript. Currently, I don't know of a way to get that to work through pure CSS.

I hope this helps.
Hristo

---

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qrUAy/

Matthew James Taylor's site is actually quite good and his layouts are definitely not a hoax :) But you have a right to your opinion. Anyway, here's the simple header/content/footer layout...

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-1-column-full-page-pixels.htm

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: Ok, I tried really hard to understand what's so special about the "1-column-full-page" layout described there. But I failed. I even removed lots of text in the content area to see how it is displayed when the page actually gets smaller than the screen but still it's a normal website with a footer directly under the body. If there weren't other layouts available on this website  I would think that this website is a hoax.

Comment: I updated my post with a link to an example. Let me know what you think.

Comment: No. Doesn't work. The center element doesn't fill the remaining space (Give it a background color to see) and the footer has a fixed size. As I said in the question the size of the header and footer is dynamic.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the header and footer being dynamic?

Comment: Example: If the header is a english text then it is pretty short and fits into one line. If it is translated to french then it gets pretty long and needs two lines. So the height of the header and footer must be kept at "auto" (The default for div elements) so they grow when the content needs more space.

Answer (score 0):

If necessary, just set the width of a table to something like 98%.

You didn't post your CSS code. Did you try setting the height of the `head` and `foot` classes? Alternatively, just let them size to the content.

Bottom line: Your HTML looks okay. (The only problem you described involved a table using HTML you didn't even post.) What's wrong with the HTML you posted?

Comment: I'm searching for working CSS. I haven't posted CSS because I don't have working CSS. That's my problem. And I mentioned a table because I tried it with a table instead of using divs (as I wrote) but this was also not working. So it's not a requirement to keep this HTML code with the four divs. If there is a solution using a table or more divs then this is fine as long as it matches the listed characteristics.

Comment: @kayahr: I'm hesitant to respond because I'm just going to ask the same question again. What's wrong with the HTML you posted?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it (Beside the fact that I can't find working CSS code to get the result I need). It's just an example which is kind of a starting point to begin with. It's not a requirement that exactly this HTML code must be used.

Comment: @kayahr: If there's no problem with the code you posted, then you have your answer already.

Comment: Ok, looks like this leads to nothing. Let's start over and let me comment your original answer paragraph by paragraph. 1) Why should setting the table to a width of 98% help when this is a vertical layout? 2) The height of the head and foot is dynamic so it must stay at "auto". The problem is how to setup the height of the center element. 3) Yes, the HTML looks okay but I'm missing CSS code for it so this HTML appears as described. But if the problem can be solved with totally different HTML code then this is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could use relative and absolute positioning. Make the content 100% height of your browser window; absolutely position your header to the top of your screen; similarly absolutely position your footer to the bottom of the page; and then in another `<div>` inside your content `<div>` set `margin-top` the same height as your header, and `padding-bottom` the same height as your footer.

Your HTML would be something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div class="inner">
          <!-- place margins on this element -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>
```

Then your CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#content .inner {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

This *is* untested and written off-the-cuff, so may need some tweaking, but that's the premise.

Also, I prefer to use IDs for elements such as headers, footers, main content wrappers as theoretically there's only every going to be one on a page.

Comment: Doesn't fit. As I wrote: The sizes are unknown at creation time. The content in the header and footer is dynamic. So I can't specify any margins for the center element.

Comment: You *must* know the size of your header and footer. What type of website *are* you creating?!

Comment: What law says that I need to know the sizes of the header and footer? And I never said it is a web site. It is only a PART of a web site. A box with the size 512x512 in the example. The header/footer could contain dynamic text which may fit into one line or may wrap into two lines. Depends on the length of the text. If I knew all the sizes then this would be pretty easy and there would be no reason to ask questions.

Comment: @kayahr I'm sure there's a specific reason, but I'm sat here scratching my head. I'm not sure something that flexible is achievable through raw HTML and CSS, as you're wanting to affect the box model of one container based on sibling containers.

Comment: This flexibility works flawlessly with a horizontal table. The old-school table-based column layouts can do this. Specify width=100% for the center cell and it always takes the space which is not needed by the left or right cell. But unfortunately I need it for a vertical layout. But IE7 doesn't like it. So it's nearly working and I'm just hoping someone knows some nice trick to get it working in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

By superfluous I menat the example had too much markup.  try:

```
<style>
.box {
    width: 512px; height: 512px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.head {
    background:white;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.foot {
    width:100%;
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>

<div class="box">
    <div class="head">This is the header</div>
    <p>The is the center area</p>
    <div class="foot">This is the footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I repeat what's already in the question: "The center area takes all the other space. And with this I mean it REALLY takes all the space and it is not just positioned at the top of the center." Your example does exactly this: It absolutely positions the footer at the bottom of the parent container and that's it. The p-element (The center area) doesn't fill all the remaining space. Give it a background color and you'll see.

Comment: By the way: This question isn't about markup. I know how to use the style tag instead of inline styles and I know that I should use semantically matching tags but I tried to keep the example small. And the center area could also be a picture, or a java applet or who knows what. That's why I simply used divs in the example.

Comment: Change the .box background color and it does exactly what you want.

Comment: No. It's not about having a specific color somewhere. The background color is just an example to prove that the center element has NOT taken the remaining space. Forget about the background color and let's say the center element is an image which must take up the remaining space between the header and the footer so it's stretched into this remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

Revised to include an image as an example:

```
<style>
.box {
    width: 512px; height: 512px;
    background:url("http://www.desktops-wallpapers.com/Exports%20from%20Aperture/Trees/1280_1024/row_of_pine_trees.jpg");
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.head {
    background:white;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.foot {
    width:100%;
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:2;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>

<div class="box">
    <div class="head">This is the header</div>
    <p>The is the center area</p>
    <div class="foot">This is the footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Having a background image instead of a background color doesn't make it better ;-) The p-element is still not filling the remaining area between head and foot. And that's the point. I don't need workarounds to make it look like the center is filling the remaining space I need the center element to REALLY fill the space between header and footer. So even forget about the image, replace the <p> element with a <textarea>. This text area must fill the space between head and foot.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching on this and found this link that describes a trick to do something similar to what you want. The only different is that if the content is bigger than the page size, the content will scroll. I found it useful, though, and will do this for my web page.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/

```
body { margin: 0 }
.row, .col { overflow: hidden; position: absolute; }
.row { left: 0; right: 0; }
.col { top: 0; bottom: 0; }
.scroll-x { overflow-x: auto; }
.scroll-y { overflow-y: auto; }

.header.row { height: 122px; top: 0; background-color: red;}
.body.row { top: 122px; bottom: 24px; background-color: yellow;}
.footer.row { height: 24px; bottom: 0; background-color: green;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<body>
    <div class="header row">
        <h2>My header</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="body row scroll-y">
        The body        
    </div>

    <div class="footer row">
        My footer
    </div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```